# String interpolation in perl

Tags: perl, string-interpolation, widechar

I am new to perl, I am learning using `O'reillys Learning Perl` book. Unicode characters(as written in the book) like this  `♠` can be printed using `print "\x{2668}"`.  I was using `foreach loop` to print a range of Unicode characters.

Example: from 2660 - 2670;

I have written the following code,

```
foreach $num (2660..2670)
{
        print "Character for $num  is:","\x{$num} \n";

}
```

Which was giving the following output,

```
Illegal hexadecimal digit '$' ignored at ./Printing_messages.pl line 10.
Character for 2660  is: 
Character for 2661  is: 
Character for 2662  is: 
Character for 2663  is: 
Character for 2664  is: 
Character for 2665  is: 
Character for 2666  is: 
Character for 2667  is: 
Character for 2668  is: 
Character for 2669  is: 
Character for 2670  is:
```

After that I've made some other tweaks, but nothing worked. What is the problem with the my program ? I don't understand. Is there how to make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
print "Character for $num is: ", chr($num), "\n";
```

Answer (score -3):

You can write something like :

```
foreach $num (2660..2670)
{
        print "Character for $num  is:",eval(qq!\"\\x{$num} \\n\"!);
}
```

The problem with your original program, is that perl cannot evaluate "\x{...}" because this evaluation is done before the interpolation of $num.

Comment: Its Working. Thank you. is `eval` a function ?

Comment: Generating a Perl program, compiling it and running it is severe overkill.

Comment: Using `eval()` for this is seriously bad form. Consider the `chr()` function instead, as the other answer shows.

Comment: This program was for educative usage only. I was answering to the "I am learning..." thing. Of course char is a better solution, but his program was not meant to be production quality... I thought he was trying to use the \x{} syntax...